# Cubic spline with circular predictor

Tags: curve-fitting, splines, circular-statistics, interpolation

I have a set of observations $y_i$ for a set of values of the independent variable $x_i$. $x_i$ takes values of angles, so it is a circular variable. Is there some method to perform cubic splines or some interpolation on the values of $y_i$, taking into account the circularity of $x_i$? Extra points if there exists a Python implementation :)

Comment: Did you consider [searching our site first](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=circular+spline)?  BTW, there's a simple hack when all you have is a spline function: triple your dataset by copying the responses into the period before your data and again into the period after your data.  Fit any spline, then extract the middle third.

Comment: Thanks, I did search but didn't find that, and didn't come up in "similar questions". Although evidently is wasn't a thorough enough search.

Comment: Great proposed hack btw. I think I'll go with that